# Solving $L=\sqrt{(D-h\tan\theta)^2+(H-h\cos\theta)^2 } $ for $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm finding it herculean to solve for $\theta$ in the following equation. Kindly help please:
$$ L=\sqrt{(D-h\tan\theta)^2+(H-h\cos\theta)^2 } $$

Comment: Please use mathJax for math symbols. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's done now. Thank you.

Comment: I've manipulated this into a degree-$8$ polynomial in $\cos\theta$. Solving such a thing symbolically is therefore unlikely. Numerical methods would appear to be necessary.

Comment: Is $\theta$ supposed to be small ? Please give a range if any.

Comment: Hello @ClaudeLeibovici . Thank you for responding. Yes,  θ is supposed to be small. Take from 0 to pi: not less than 0, not greater than pi.

Comment: @Blue Thank you. Can you guide me to a numerical method I can apply

Comment: How small is $\theta$? If very small indeed and in radians, then the equation becomes $$L^2=(D-h\theta)^2+(H-h(1-\frac 12\theta^2))^2,$$ which is quartic in $\theta$ and thus more manageable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tangent half-angle substitution $\theta=2 \tan ^{-1}(x)$, we end with
$$\sum_{n=0}^8 a_n\,x^n=0$$ the coefficients being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & D^2+(h-H)^2-L^2 \\
 1 & -4 D h \\
 2 & 4 h H \\
 3 & -4 D h \\
 4 & -2 \left(D^2-7 h^2+H^2-L^2\right) \\
 5 & 4 D h \\
 6 & -4 h H \\
 7 & 4 D h \\
 8 & D^2+(h+H-L) (h+H+L)
\end{array}
\right)$$ and again an octic polynomial as @Blue already commented.

Solving for all the roots is not a problem since there are plenty of subroutines available for all coding environments.

Now, what we can **try** is to consider that this expression as a Taylor series to $O(x^9)$ and use series reversion. This would give
$$x=t+a_1\sum_{n=2}^8 b_n\,u^n \qquad \text{with}\qquad t=-\frac {a_0}{a_1} \qquad \text{and}\qquad u=\frac {t}{a_1}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & b_n \\
 2 & -a_2 \\
 3 & 2 a_2^2-a_1 a_3 \\
 4 & -5 a_2^3+5 a_1 a_3 a_2-a_1^2 a_4 \\
 5 & 14 a_2^4-21 a_1 a_3 a_2^2+6 a_1^2 a_4 a_2+a_1^2 \left(3 a_3^2-a_1
   a_5\right) \\
 6 & -42 a_2^5+84 a_1 a_3 a_2^3-28 a_1^2 a_4 a_2^2+7 a_1^2 \left(a_1
   a_5-4 a_3^2\right) a_2+a_1^3 (7 a_3 a_4-a_1 a_6)
\end{array}
\right)$$

Coefficients $b_7$ and $b_8$ are really too long for being printed here but they are available upon request.

For a single test, using $D=100$, $h=20$, $H=50$, $L=95$, using the above approach, we  end with
$$x=\frac{9233947126838127045}{36893488147419103232}$$ which leads to
$\color{blue}{\theta=0.4904968}$ while the exact solution is
$\color{red}{\theta=0.4904992}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I get the other coefficients please? And I'm really interested in how you came about those - by hand? please show me the way. Thank you.

Comment: @Peelo. Send me an e-mail (address in my profile). They are monsters ! What I would like is that, using your own values, you compute the approximate result summing successively to $2,3,4,\cdots$.  I suppose it could converge quite fast. In any manner, you will need to polish the root using this as a guess for Newton method. Cheers :-) By the way, if this is an answer, may be, you could accept it